# Motion of the atmosphere

Tags: forces

There is a cloud floating stationary above me, so the cloud must be rotating the same speed as I am.

The top of the cloud must be moving faster and farther than the ground. How is this possible?

What force pushes the top around faster than the ground?

Comment: Usually clouds move across the sky, sometimes very fast, sometimes slow. A stationary cloud is not common.

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of the following:
[image]

The tangential velocities at top and bottom are not the same for otherwise the cloud would disperse.  Of course in practice the cloud is not a solid object either, so various factors, such as pressure, local windes etc, affect the velocities of different parts of the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **gravity**!

Particles moving in a circular path follow this formula:

$$a=\frac{v^2}r$$

where $r$ is the distance (to Earth centre), $v$ the speed and $a$ the radial acceleration inwards. This acceleration changes the direction constantly, so that you have a smooth circular motion as opposed to a straight path.

A particle further away with bigger $r$ will have to either decrease $a$ and/or increase $v$ so that the formula still holds.

Now, in the case of gravity on a cloud, the top and bottom are so close to each other that the gravitational acceleration is as good as the same. We'll call it $g$. So, since $a=g$ is the same for both top and bottom particles, and they have different distances $r$, they must also have different $v$. The pull that gravity does is therefore the cause of different $v$'s.

The difference is still very small, though, seen in perspective of the Earth's size. Any drift wind could pull all cloud particles along the same direction easily.

Answer (score 0):

This does have an effect. Another one is Corialis Effect. See http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/glossary/coriolis_effect.html But neither of these make much difference over short distances. It might begin to be noticeable over 10 miles. A small wind is more important over shorter distances.

Comment: Unclear. What is "this"?

Comment: @sammygerbil - I guess that wasn't clear. The larger circumference at higher altitude has an effect. But like the Calvin and Hobbes record, nothing prevents the top of the cloud from having a higher speed and keeping up with the bottom of the cloud. If the bottom rose in an updraft, its slower speed would make it get left behind. It would be deflected sideways as it rose. This is the Corialis effect. But over a short distance, the deflection would be too small to notice.